# Does `this` reliably equal the element triggering the event in inline event handlers across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, this, dom-events

Will the following log itself upon getting clicked in every browser?

```
<a href="#" onclick="console.log(this);">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for inline html attribute event handlers `this` is reliably the element in question.

However your example with `console.log(this)` will *not* work in every browser, because not all browsers have a console, and certain browsers *with* a console give an error unless the console is actually open when the `console.log()` statement executes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes it does.

This is a standard behavior of `this`. It even works for event handlers assigned using javascript.

Comment: _"It even works for event handlers assigned using javascript"_ - Not if you use IE's `.attachEvent()` to assign your handlers.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Hmm.. didn't know about that. I usually just do the `onclick=` thing.

Comment: @slebetman—it's a standard behaviour of **browsers**, `this` is an ECMAScript feature. ;-)

Comment: @nnnnnn: If it works for event handlers assigned using javascript, then why do you see folks using `e.target` all the time?

Comment: @adlwalrus - I don't see folks using `e.target` all the time, just some of the time. In my own code I generally only use `e.target` when handling events that have already bubbled up from the original target element, i.e., in situations when `this` is not the same as `e.target`.